# How do I use babel-root-import with babelify using Laravel Elixir's Browserify option?

Tags: javascript, npm, browserify, babeljs, laravel-elixir

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-vueify');

mix.browserify('app.js')
```

works great, but I'm looking to add babel-root-import so I can avoid

```
import Module from '../../../../../modules.js'
```

From my understanding, after npm install babel-root-import, I can edit the Config.js settings for elixir

https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-root-import

This is the confusing part. Do I put this under 'browserify' or under 'babelify' for the Config.js? Then again, vueify is doing the browserify stuff, so I'm confused how babel-root-import can integrate.

```
{   "plugins": 
    [
        ["babel-root-import", {
            "rootPathSuffix": "src/js"
        }]   
    ] 
}
```

Thanks a bunch, this node.js stuff is madly confusing.